# JQuery or C# to check when "Checked" multi checkbox is true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I select data from database and bind data by asp:Repeater.
I create checkbox in ItemTemplate and receive data from database.
I want to update data in database when I "checked" on checkbox on any rows.

protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {

```
        //*** Level ID ***//
        Label lblLevelID = (Label)(e.Item.FindControl("lblLevelID"));
        if ((e.Item.FindControl("lblLevelID") != null))
        {
            lblLevelID.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "LevelID").ToString();
            strLevelID = lblLevelID.Text;
            //MyArr[Convert.ToInt16(In), 0] = strLevelID;
        }
```

...

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1" style="font-size:12px;" width="800">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>  
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="25"><asp:Label id="lblLevelID" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" width="350"><asp:Label id="lblLevelDesc" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" width="25"><asp:Label id="lblChoiceID" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="left" width="350"><asp:Label id="lblChoiceDesc" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" width="50"><%--<input type="checkbox" id="chkSelected" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelected_OnCheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="True" />--%>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>           
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: How is jQuery related to that question?

Comment: @user1734077 Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in myRepeater.Items)
{
  CheckBox chkbx = rpItem.FindControl("chkSelected") as CheckBox;
  if (chkbx.Checked)
  {
    //your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: //*** Selected ***//
            CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox)(e.Item.FindControl("chkSelected"));
            if ((e.Item.FindControl("chkSelected") != null))
            {
                if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Selected").ToString() == "True")
                {
                    chkSelected.Checked = true;
                }
            }                                                        I use this code for show data from database but I want check "Checkbox.Checked" when I want to update data.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelected" runat="server" CssClass="sb" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    if($(".cb").is(":checked"))
    {
        alert("Well done!");
    }

});

</script>
```

If you want register a change event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".cb").live("change", function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
            alert("I am checked!");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("I am unchecked!");
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

hope it helps

Comment: I try to buttom code but it alert only "I am unchecked!".

Comment: when you check it, it should alert "I am checked!" and when you uncheck it, it shoudl alert "I am unchecked!". please, explain well what you have done and where you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this code

```
 protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    { 

        //*** Level ID ***//
        Label lblLevelID = (Label)(e.Item.FindControl("lblLevelID"));
        if ((e.Item.FindControl("lblLevelID") != null))
        {
            lblLevelID.Text = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "LevelID").ToString();
            strLevelID = lblLevelID.Text;
            //MyArr[Convert.ToInt16(In), 0] = strLevelID;
        }
        //*** Selected ***//
        CheckBox chkSelected = (CheckBox)(e.Item.FindControl("chkSelected"));
        if ((e.Item.FindControl("chkSelected") != null))
        {
            if (DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Selected").ToString() == "True")
            {
                chkSelected.Checked = true;
                if (chkSelected.Checked)
                {
                    UpdateData0();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                chkSelected.Checked = false;
                if (chkSelected.Checked)
                {
                    UpdateData1();
                }
            }

        }
```

It's display data from database but no update when I "checked" on Checkbox.